# Notepad++ replace whole string except integer in it

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex

I have a string in **Notpad++**.

> CAST(1 AS NUMERIC(18, 0)),

I want to remove all string except 1 in it.

> 1 will be any integer here.

I need a regex to replace it.

Every type of help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: "_I need a regex to replace it._" Have you done some research and tried to solve this on your own yet? How is this question related to `PHP` or `MySQL`?

Comment: StackOverflow requires some type of language where it belongs. I am working on PHP, therefore, I write this.

Comment: SQL Server does not have built-in regular expression support, so you cannot do this using regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

```
CAST\(([0-9]+).+$
```

And replace with

```
\1
```

Which will leave just the contents of the capture group, The (..) is a capture group that puts what is inside it into {n} where {n} is the capture groups number. In this case we have only 1 so it's \1 for the replacement.  And our capture group is `0` to `9` any number of times in a row (as explained below)

[For example](https://regex101.com/r/lgBMjP/1)

- `CAST\(` matches `CAST(` literally
- `([0-9]+)` capture `(...)` 0-9 (`+` one or more), you could do `(\d+)` too
- `.+$` anything one or more to the `$` end of the line.

If there is other text on this line such as

```
 CAST(1 AS NUMERIC(18, 0)), Some other Text
```

You'll have to use something more specific then `.+$` such as

```
 CAST\((\d+) AS NUMERIC\(\d+,\s*\d+\)\),
```

Which is the same as the above except the last line in the explanation:

- `.+$` anything one or more to the `$` end of the line.

Will be this

- `AS NUMERIC\(` or  `AS NUMERIC(` literally
- `\d+` any integer
- `,` the comma literally
- `\s*` whitespace `*` none or more.
- `\d+` again
- `\)\),` or `)),` literally.

You have to escape the `(` and `)` it knows they are not capture groups.

[Example](https://regex101.com/r/lgBMjP/3)

The result in this case will be

```
1 some other text
```

In the first example it would also remove `some other text`, I don't know if extra text exists so I put both just for completeness.

Regular expressions can be very confusing when you first start using them, but they are extremely powerful.  It's worth taking the time to learn at least the basics as there is so much you can do with them.

Your Notepad++ replace dialog should look like this:

[image]

And press REPLACE ALL

Thanks to @Caius Jard for the screenshot.

hope that helps!!

Comment: the replaced integer can be any type of integer.
how can I write it?

Comment: last I checked an integer has to be 0-9 one or more.  Such as `1` is an integer, so is `890078484993`.  Ergo both `[0-9]+` and `\d+` will match them all.

Comment: To explain, `[...]` is a set of characters in this case 0 to 9,  `+` is one or more.  Also `\d` is digit or shorthand for `0-9`. The `(..)` is a capture group that puts what is inside it into `\{n}` where `{n}` is the capture groups number.  In this case we have only 1 so it's `\1` for the replacement.

Comment: Thanks for your response...!

1 Can be 123 or 2015, 4666546.
How can I exempt these integer values on replacement

Comment: 1 Can be 123 or 2015 or 4666546 or 874984939348983498983489439898348943899843898394984389984  [Example](https://regex101.com/r/lgBMjP/4)  or any arbitrarily long string of 0 to 9

Comment: Might be worth noting that the \1 means "the first set of numbers captured by the expression in the brackets". It doesn't help that the regex results in a 1 being output from group 1. If the data being worked on was `CAST(123 as NUMERIC(18,0))` then the first capturing group \1 would contain `123`

Comment: @CaiusJard - I did in the comments `The (..) is a capture group that puts what is inside it into \{n} where {n} is the capture groups number. In this case we have only 1 so it's \1 for the replacement.` I'll put it in the answer too.

Comment: Oh, I agree.. just a different wording sometimes helps. It's kinda bad luck that this isn't an easy exampl data to start on, because it contains a 1 \1 confusion, and also ( brackets in the source data *and* the regular expression..

Comment: I agree, it's also easy to forget how confusing Regex can be when you first see it after you been using it for 8 some years Like I have.... lol.  it's like its own language.  The only thing that troubles me is look(arounds).  other then that it's like English to me now.

Comment: (If you want to take the picture out of the answer I just subbed, and flow it into your answer somewhere, I'll remove my answer - it's more an edit proposal :))

Comment: Sure, glad I (we) could help you.  Good luck!